# SQL Live Backup Over Intermittent Connection

Tags: postgresql, rsync, database-replication

I have a few PCs that have local PostgreSQL databases running, just logging data. Data is only ever inserted, never removed or updated. The remote PCs are connected to the internet by cellular modem and depending on their location, often do not have internet access. When they do have an internet connection I would like them to push a copy of their databases to a central location and keep the remote database up to date with any new data. Essentially, I need an 'rsync' for databases.

At first it seemed like what I need is to set up PostgreSQL Hot-Standby but I'm unsure if this is actually what I need because my situation seems to differ from the examples I've seen.

1. Each remote PC has a Postgres server with a single database that has a unique name, the tables within the DBs have generic names. I would like to synchronize these databases to a single remote Postgres server. I think this should be okay due to the unique DB names.
2. My connectivity is very intermittent, days to weeks without a connection. I've seen PgAdmin be very reliable despite a terrible (cellular) internet connection, if Postges Hot-Standby is the same I may be alright.

As far as I can see my options are either to set up PostgreSQL Hot-Standby, or roll my own solution. I don't want to roll my own solution. However it is simple enough if I can't find anything better; a Python daemon run by systemd to find the diff between the local and remote DB, then push the new rows from the local to the remote DB. But I'm sure someone has solved this problem, I just haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need hot standby (which is the PostgreSQL term for being able to query the replicated database), but streaming replication. You need a central standby server for each intermittently connected remote database server. If you use replication slots, you can be sure that replication will never fall behind.